# Xcode Linker issues

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, bitcode

Im writing to you as I am deeply in need of some assistance.

I'm trying to compile an app to my iPhone from Xcode, however, I keep encountering the issue of having this error come up when I press run:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F2'
ld: '/Users/[My-name]/Documents/XCode Projects/Store Testing Projects Here/BallGame 1.1/StartApp.framework/StartApp(STAJsonAd.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Now, I have checked and made sure that both my framework search paths and Library search paths are both *empty*. This is why I am having such an issue, I cannot for the life of me figure out the issue here! Why is Xcode trying to link something that is not specified to link to!

Thanks in advance, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have more than one TARGETS?
2. You can change the value in Build Settings→Build Options→Enable BitCode to NO.